# Validate regex in Swift

Tags: regex, swift

Is it any way to validate regular expression in Swift that syntax of regex is correct?

E.g. user enters regex in TextField and I need to validate that one's syntax is correct.

Comment: Using `regularExpressionWithPattern:options:error:`, it should throws an `NSError` if pattern is invalid.

Comment: @Larme you should post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc:

[+ regularExpressionWithPattern:options:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRegularExpression/regularExpressionWithPattern:options:error:)

For `error` parameter:

> An out value that returns any error encountered
>   during initialization. **Returns an `NSError` object if the regular
>   expression pattern is invalid**; otherwise returns `nil`.

[- initWithPattern:options:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/initWithPattern:options:error:)

For `error` parameter:

> An out value that returns any error encountered during initialization.
>   **Returns an `NSError` object if the regular expression pattern is
>   invalid**; otherwise returns `nil`.