# How to check if a Regex is valid or not in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I got a Regex from an API. I need to validate the regex if it is valid or not.

This is a sample regex pattern:

`/^[a-z0-9_-]{6,18}$/`

I need to validate this string.

**Edit:** I have tried [initwithpattern](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1410900-initwithpattern) with a invalid regex `[`, But its not throwing any error.

Comment: validating the regex means that you want to apply it or check if it's a valid regex?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Agreed with @AhmadF. For the last one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743099/validate-regex-in-swift for the first one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784447/swift-regex-does-a-string-match-a-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize an instance of `NSRegularExpression` with the given regex pattern and check whether that `NSRegularExpression` is `NULL`.

```
NSString *regexString = @"/^[a-z0-9_-]{6,18}$/";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = 
    [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString 
                                              options:0 
                                                error:&error];

if (!regex) {
    //regex is invalid
}
```

Comment: No. The *correct* way to check for failure or success of Cocoa methods is to check the *return value* (in this case for `NULL`). Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384218/swift-idiomatic-error-checking, which has a link to the Apple documentation.

Comment: @MartinR Noted, this is some valuable piece of information. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: i have tried [initwithpattern](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1410900-initwithpattern) with a invalid regex. No luck. But this is working.

Comment: `[` isn't a valid regex. `[` is a special character. If you want to validate a string of type `[restOfMyString`, you need to escapde the `[` doing `\[`. Here is a great memo about regex, and showing the char to escape if needed: https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/downloads/RW-NSRegularExpression-Cheatsheet.pdf